# No access to Google Cloud Storage bucket after installing new Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, access-denied, bucket

I had to remove and reinstall Google Cloud Storage and Google Bigquery. Since then I don't have access to the bucket I created before (error message is `"Access denied"`). I also can't find the bucket in Google APIs Console. How do I get access to the bucket again?

Comment: I've answered below, but a side question: did you delete the project from the console while you still had data that you needed in the bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deleted the project, then any buckets associataed with the project are gone along with it.  Access denied can happen for a period of time while the buckets are still being cleaned up.  Eventually this access denied error should turn into a Not Found error and you should be able to re-create a bucket with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, no it seems I deleted the bucket by mistake. Project is still there.